# filter_all with relative columns position (filter in any col. then in n+2 col)

Tags: r, dplyr

Short question about how to express *n+2* in col specification with `filter_all` or `filter`.

I need to search for a specific value followed, two cols. away, by specific value, without using col. names

### Data

I have a df that comes from text processing (in Old French, btw). Each row represent a line of the text. Here's an extract of that df (simplified). It continues after col. SYLL_TAG4-1 up to SYLL_TAG20.

```
   meter SYLL_TAG1 `SYLL_TAG1 -1` SYLL_TAG2 `SYLL_TAG2 -1` SYLL_TAG3 `SYLL_TAG3 -1` SYLL_TAG4 `SYLL_TAG4 -1` SYLL_TAG5 `SYLL_TAG5 -1`     
 1    11 jo        NA             më        NA             crend     NA             rei       NA             ë         NA            
 2    11 ë         NA             dit       NA             al        NA             cun       NA             të        NA            
 3    11 liv       NA             rez       NA             lë        NA             mei       NA             jo        NA            
 4    11 dist      NA             ar        NA             ce        NA             ves       NA             quë       NA            
 5    11 dë        NA             voz       NA             ma        NA             na        NA             ces       NA            
 6    11 mais      NA             u         NA             në        NA             cho       NA             së        NA            
 7    11 jo        NA             oi        NA             al        NA             cor       NA             ner       NA            
 8    11 si        re             a         NA             pιed      NA             es        NA             tes       NA            
 9    11 jo        NA             ai        NA             cun       NA             té        NA             i         NA            
10    11 est       NA             reu       NA             li        NA             tind      NA             rent      NA            
11    11 a         NA             ces       te             es        NA             pe        NA             ë         NA
```

Here's the code to reproduce the df (sorry for the verbose):

```
PAM_JO <- structure(list(meter = c(11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11), SYLL_TAG1 = c("jo", "ë", "liv", "dist", "dë", "mais", 
"jo", "si", "jo", "est", "a"), `SYLL_TAG1 -1` = c("NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "re", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG2 = c("më", 
"dit", "rez", "ar", "voz", "u", "oi", "a", "ai", "reu", "ces"
), `SYLL_TAG2 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "te"), SYLL_TAG3 = c("crend", "al", "lë", 
"ce", "ma", "në", "al", "pιed", "cun", "li", "es"), `SYLL_TAG3 -1` = c("NA", 
"NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), 
    SYLL_TAG4 = c("rei", "cun", "mei", "ves", "na", "cho", "cor", 
    "es", "té", "tind", "pe"), `SYLL_TAG4 -1` = c("NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG5 = c("ë", 
    "të", "jo", "quë", "ces", "së", "ner", "tes", "i", "rent", 
    "ë"), `SYLL_TAG5 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG6 = c("quë", "jo", 
    "en", "jo", "cul", "vos", "quë", "ë", "ad", "nei", "quë"
    ), `SYLL_TAG6 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG7 = c("vos", "në", 
    "fe", "i", "vert", "soi", "guai", "jo", "mais", "mes", "jo"
    ), `SYLL_TAG7 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG8 = c("vos", "vus", 
    "rai", "rai", "jo", "jo", "res", "sui", "quë", "ë", "ai"
    ), `SYLL_TAG8 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG9 = c("mes", "aim", 
    "la", "par", "ai", "ben", "në", "a", "sept", "jo", "cein"
    ), `SYLL_TAG9 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "te"), SYLL_TAG10 = c("li", "ni", 
    "jus", "mun", "es", "gua", "viv", "ce", "li", "ce", "i"), 
    `SYLL_TAG10 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG11 = c("sez", "ent", "ti", 
    "chef", "soign", "rant", "rat", "val", "we", "rans", "ci"
    ), `SYLL_TAG11 -1` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), SYLL_TAG12 = c("NA", "NA", 
    "ce", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "es", "NA", "NA"), `SYLL_TAG12 -1` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"
    ), NUM_L = c(257, 306, 498, 799, 1232, 1520, 2106, 2136, 
    2757, 3111, 3830)), row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

### Task

I want to find lines matching specific text context.

***a) Find line containing a word: easy!***

First, I wanted to filter it so that I get every line that contains the word "jo" in a column and that have value "11" in the meter col. Easy:

```
library(tidyverse)

PAM_text_tag %>%
    filter_all(any_vars(. == "jo")) %>%
    filter(meter=="11")
```

That's actually what gave the illustrated df above.

***b) Find line containing a word followed two col. away by specific content***

But now I want to be able to filter it to get only the lines containing "jo" followed by a vowel initial word. Given the structure of the df (that I prefer not to change), I'd have to look what happens two colums after the "jo" : if "jo" is in SYLL_TAG3, there is nothing in SYLL_TAG3-1 and I need to check if SYLL_TAG4 starts with a vowel.

**Goal:** The filtered output should only contains rows 4, 5, 6, 8, 10 and 12 (only rows in which the cell containing "jo" is followed by an empty cell followed by a cell beginning by a vowel).

### My question

The question is: how do I express the *n+2* thing in the columns' location without having to use col. names? (I don't know in which col. "jo" will show up)

### Supplementary material

List of all vowels used in that text:

> aeiouyäëïöüÿáéíóúàèìòùâêîôû

I guess I just have to use `str_detect` with `pattern="^[aeiouyäëïöüÿáéíóúàèìòùâêîôû]"` to match de vowel initial words. My question is more about how to express the *n+2* thing than about regex in `filter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one base R option :

```
#Get the row column index where 'jo' is present
mat <- which(PAM_JO == 'jo', arr.ind = TRUE)
#Add 1 to column index to compare with NA
mat1 <- cbind(mat[, 1], mat[, 2] + 1)
#Add 2 to column index to compare with vowels
mat2 <- cbind(mat[, 1], mat[, 2] + 2)

#convert to dataframe
PAM_JO <- data.frame(PAM_JO)
#Create a logical vector
inds <- PAM_JO[mat1] == 'NA' & grepl('^[aeiou]', PAM_JO[mat2])
#Subset the data
result <- PAM_JO[mat[, 1][inds], ]
```